# Infinite Loop and Dead Code For Loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

This Method is supposed to look through an arraylist of TV series objects. However, the j++ in my for loop is giving a dead code error, and inputting a title not currently saved in the arraylist causes an infinite loop. No idea why. SOS
Edit; The Lecturer who set this assignment isn't allowing the use of iterators

```
public void deleteseries(Scanner sc){

    System.out.println("Enter the Title of the Series you want to Remove");
    System.out.println("Cureent Series Stored: ");
    for (TV_Series tv:series) {
        System.out.println(tv.getTitle());
    }
    String title_to_delete = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    boolean found = false;
    do{
        for(int j = 0; j < series.size(); j++){
            if (series.get(j).getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title_to_delete))
                {
                    series.remove(j);
                    System.out.println("Series Removed");
                    found=true;
                    //Jump out of loop

                    break;
                }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("No Results for Title "+title_to_delete);
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
        }   
    }while(found==false);
}
```

Comment: *What* `i++` in the for loop?

Comment: You *do* break out of the `for` loop kind of unconditionally. So the "increment" part of the loop never needs to run.

Comment: why do you have nested loops if you are only searching through one record?

Comment: You need to remove the do while loop. Just the for loop will do your job. In case when the title is found your code will run fine, in other case even though your for loop will end after running through all the series but the found will never be set to true and thus the do while loop will keep on processing. It is not required.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger and you will be able to see you have a few errors. e.g. there is no sense having a loop if you always break. There is no point setting `found = false;` if it is already false.

Answer (score 1):

There are several related issues here; I think you may need to review how looping structures work from the top.

You've coded a `for` loop that should iterate over the array; that's fine.  But instead of letting it iterate, you've set it up to break from the loop during the 1st iteration.  I assume you enclosed it in a `do-while` loop because you noticed that it wasn't iterating, but that just re-runs the first iteration of the loop over and over.  Also, the exit condition of the `do-while` loop would be `found` turning `true`, which is why the loop doesn't exit if a match isn't found.

Generally you don't need to enclose a `for` in a `while` to get iteration; `for` is a loop structure all by itself.  The only reason your `for` wouldn't iterate on its own is that you put in `break` statements; the use of `break` to exit a `for` loop is only needed if you want to abort the iteration.  So it might make sense to `break` in the `if` block, but certainly not the `else` block.

Lastly, the `else` block as written will run for every iteration (once the other issues are fixed); it doesn't make sense to say "no match found" on every iteration.  You could put an `if` block *after* the `for` loop to print an error if the loop ran through all iterations without finding a match (i.e. if `found` is still false).

Comment: So remove the do-while loop and the else statement, and place an if outside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your `if` and `else` part are `break`ing out of the internal `for` loop.

Also, If you want to find and remove, just use below:

Also, I used iterator because the list is going to be modified while looping.

```
public void deleteseries(Scanner sc){

    System.out.println("Enter the Title of the Series you want to Remove");
    System.out.println("Cureent Series Stored: ");
    for (TV_Series tv:series) {
        System.out.println(tv.getTitle());
    }
    String title_to_delete = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    boolean found = false;
    //do{
        for(Iterator<TV_Series> itr = series.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
            TV_Series tvs = itr.next();
            if (tvs.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title_to_delete))
                {
                    itr.remove();
                    System.out.println("Series Removed");
                    found=true;
                    //Jump out of loop

                    break;
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    System.out.println("No Results for Title "+title_to_delete);
                //    found = false;
                //    break;
                //}
        }   
//    }while(found==false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When modifing iterable Collections I would strongly recommend using iterators to prevent "ConcurrentModificationException". Also I've deleted some redundant code like do-while part to fix i++ problem and for cleaner code. Check my proposition:

```
public void deleteseries(Scanner sc){

    System.out.println("Enter the Title of the Series you want to Remove");
    System.out.println("Cureent Series Stored: ");
    for (TV_Series tv:series) {
        System.out.println(tv.getTitle());
    }
    String title_to_delete = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    Iterator<TV_Series> it = series.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        TV_Series tmpSeries = it.next();
        if (tmpSeries.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title_to_delete)) {
            it.remove();
            System.out.println("Series Removed");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```